# On an Ajax page called, should I reassign post variables locally, or is it fine to access $_POST as needed?

Tags: php, variables, post

Is there a speed detriment to accessing $_POST vars versus a local copy? Should I reassign the values locally ie $newFoo = $_POST['foo']; or just access $_POST['foo'] as needed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST` is a usual variable array, there is nothing special about its speed, so use it like you use any other variable, no need to copy values.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the performance difference (if there's one) can be neglicted, so you're not obliged to redefine as "local" variables. But you may want to do so for readability reasons, although some others would prefer to keep the "$_Post" approach for exactly the same readability reason...